# Remove Python2 and related components completely in Yocto

Tags: python-3.7, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am building a custom Linux image in Yocto Zeus (Previously used Yocto Thud). I have moved all the required code to Python3 and hence don't require Python2 anymore. Is there a way we can remove python2 and its modules completely from Image

Comment: I tried the IMAGE_INSTALL_remove variable, but does not seem to work. I heard that having both python2 and python3 takes up a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of these two options

1. **PACKAGE_EXCLUDE**: Specifies packages that should not be installed into the image.

   ```
   PACKAGE_EXCLUDE_pn-target_image = " python"
   ```

> If you choose to not install a package using this variable and some other package is dependent on it (i.e. listed in a recipe's RDEPENDS variable), the OpenEmbedded build system generates a
> fatal installation error. Because the build system halts the process
> with a fatal error, you can use the variable with an iterative
> development process to remove specific components from a system.
>
> Support for this variable exists only when using the IPK and RPM
> packaging backend. Support does not exist for DEB.
> [PACKAGE_EXCLUDE definition in Yocto Mega Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PACKAGE_EXCLUDE)

2. **PNBLACKLIST**:

   ```
   PNBLACKLIST[python] = "Python2 Not supported by this distro."
   ```

> Lists recipes you do not want the OpenEmbedded build system to build.
> This variable works in conjunction with the blacklist class, which is
> inherited globally.
>
> To prevent a recipe from being built, use the PNBLACKLIST variable in
> your local.conf file.
> [PNBLACKLIST definition in Yocto Mega Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PNBLACKLIST)

Answer (score 2):

Start from an image inheriting `core-image-minimal` and add packages manually. Only the packages that are specified to be installed explicitly in your image recipe and the packages specified in `RDEPENDS` and `RRECOMMENDS` of those packages will be installed in the recipe.

Some packages are also pulled because of configuration files (machine, distro or local.conf).

If there are `RRECOMMENDS` you don't want, you can use `BAD_RECOMMENDATIONS` in your image recipe to ask the image to not pull them in.

If it's an `RDEPENDS` that you don't want, maybe it's pulled because of a selected `PACKAGECONFIG` that you don't need, in that case create a bbappend for that recipe and set `PACKAGECONFIG` accordingly.

If that still does not do it, you'll have to dig deeper into what can be removed from `RDEPENDS` and for which reason (is it a mistake? is it safe in one specific configuration in which `RDEPENDS` is not needed?).

The way to know which package is pulling which package is to use `-g` as argument of bitbake. Do not attempt to create a scheme/drawing/image from the dot files, they are too big for dot to handle properly (takes hours and the result is unusable). `"recipeA:do_foo" => "recipeB:do_bar"` means that `do_foo` task from `recipeA` depends on `do_bar` from `recipeB`.

`PACKAGE_EXCLUDE` in one of the configuration files (local.conf or distro.conf) should
also make it easier to identify which recipe needs the one recipe you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

We can use another approach to resolved this in fact it will worked for me
create a function called python3_remove(){rm -rf /usr/bin/python3* } and add this function in .bb file i,e
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "python3_remove; " after do clean build